# Android: Are Most Games on the Android Market Written In Java?

Tags: java, android

I am interested in learning about Game development for the Android Platform but one question which has always been on my mind is what programming languages are some of the more popular games written in like Angry Birds, clash of clans and boom beach etc.?

What I really want to know is has the Java I been using to create standard Android Applications be used for games?

Comment: It is more about the content of the game then the language it was written in.  Android is best in Java, but there are other alternatives.  Your question will get closed, this is for programming questions.

Comment: My android games certainly are, but this question is more of a poll. These aren't really best suited for stack overflow

Comment: Please ask **programming questions**, not our opinions.

Comment: @RichardTingle. Hi, may I ask does the java Garbage Collection cause you any performance problems on your games. This is one of my initial concerns due to small delays which can affect how smooth the game is?

Comment: @user3364963 No, obviously with games you always have to keep an eye on performance but whenever I have been doing performance optimisation the route cause has always been "this algorithm needs to be improved" rather than it being garbage collection pauses. Java has really improved over the years and with concurrent garbage collection unless you're creating **huge** numbers of short lived objects you wont have an issue (because java collects garbage as it goes along these days rather than waiting till it runs out of memory then collecting everything)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can write in C++, [Java](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/index.html), [Action Script](http://gamua.com/starling/) and many more. 
[I want to be a game developer... now what?](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/08/04/I-want-to-be-a-game-developer.aspx) is a good document you can read. I also included some popular library reference for you. Hope that this will help you.

Comment: This answer feels more like it should start "Yes but ..." Rather than "No" since java is in your list (and I've had good experiences writing games in java)

Comment: Richard is absolutely right

Comment: Yup... My mistake when I type. I removed it after that.

Answer (score 1):

The most popular engine for game development (for android particulary) is Unity3D. It is commercial and qualitative. There are some frameworks (Cocos2D(opensource), unreal engine (commercial and most popular in the past engine on C++), but I (strongly) recommend you to use Unity3D - it has a big community and low skill requirements for install-and-code.

Comment: I'm never sure about Unity3D. I've never used it as a programmer but I have played with it as an end user and whenever I see it I always know it will feel like a port. For example the back button rarely works in Unity games.

Comment: I'm sure that Unity is not bugfree engine, but i see that it is so progressive, crossplatform and fast-developable. If they have some bugs - they fix them as soon as possible. Also in 2015 Unity3D 5 release, and I think there will be a lot of new megacool features and bug fixes. Software Development is not that speciality where mainstream tools are not cool.

Comment: Indeed, as I say I haven't used it personally. It may simply be that because its so easy to use you end up with people who don't really know what they are doing using it as well as the experts